# How to know which class method is get called in PHP?

Tags: php, class, oop

As title, `$a` is Class A, and call foo function.

```
$a->foo();
```

However, Class A has many subclasses, and sub-subclasses. And some of them are using dozens of traits, implementing many interfaces. I'm not sure which subclass `$a` is.
My question is, how could I know which foo function is called? I definitely can call foo() by using incorrect params,

```
$a->foo('error');
```

And I'm gonna get error trace stack.
But how can I obtain the class name or trait name directly?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Check this example:

```
<?php

class Foo
{
    protected $who;

    public function printItem($string)
    {
        echo 'printItem (' . __CLASS__ . '): ' . $string . PHP_EOL;
        $this->who = __CLASS__;
    }

    public function getClass()
    {
        echo $this->who . PHP_EOL;
    }


}

class Bar extends Foo
{
    public function printItem($string)
    {
        echo 'printItem (' . __CLASS__ . '): ' . $string . PHP_EOL;
        $this->who = __CLASS__;
    }
}

$a = new Foo();
$b = new Bar();
$a->printItem('baz'); // Output: 'printItem (Foo): baz'
$a->getClass(); // Output: Foo
$b->printItem('baz'); // Output: 'printItem (Bar): baz'
$b->getClass(); // Output: Bar
?>
```

You can read more in:

> http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php

Comment: Thanks for comments. But it can't tell which printItem() is called. It just's print the current class name. printItem can be obtained from it's any superclasses.

Comment: @WikiOops If you see $a->printItem('baz'); the output is 'printItem (Foo): baz' is the printItem from Foo which is called.  Isn't this what you want?

Comment: @WikiOops you got some advance?

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is the demo ,try this
<?php
class myclass {
 function myclass() {
  return(true);
 }
 function myfunc1(){
  return(true);
 }
 function myfunc2(){
  return(true);
 }
}
$class_methods = get_class_methods('myclass');
// or
$class_methods = get_class_methods(new myclass());
foreach ($class_methods as $method_name) {
 echo "$method_name\n";
}

// output :myclass myfunc1 myfunc2
```

Comment: It's probably not what I want.